# php simple mod_rewrite issue on Snow Leopard

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, osx-snow-leopard

I have the following within my htaccess page:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule (.*?)$
   index.php?page=$1
  </IfModule>
```

but this does not work and gives me the Internal error (500).

but if I comment out the last two lines the page loads ok not errors but fails to d what I want it to.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   #RewriteRule (.*?)$
   #index.php?page=$1
  </IfModule>
```

Any ideas what this could be??

Mac Snow Leopard.
My directory is within DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents" and I do not use the normal http://localhost/~User/ but http://localhost/?? etc

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I have come back to this as sidelined on other things for ages. So please find my new  details below, with these details i get the following error still:

```
   Internal Server Error

   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

   Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

my url:

```
  localhost/exp/index.php
```

My htaccess:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule (.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$
  exp/index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

No wif I comment out all except the 'RewriteEngine On'

```
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteRule (.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$
  #exp/index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

I get the 403 forbidden message. I fi comment them all out the page loads.

my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file details are below:

```
 <Directory />
     Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Directory>


 <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/">
   Options Indexes MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

I use this as my localhost and not my user one localhost/~User/

So to the life of me do not knwo whats going on.

Comment: Thi smight or might not but just noticed that if I list my directories by just going to localhost then th efolder I am using is not visible??? within the list of other folders

Answer (score 0):

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php?page=URL
RewriteRule .* index.php?page=$0 [PT]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but now this will give me 403 forbidden error, and the folder has all read& wrote permissions using get info?? http://localhost/TestPages/index.php/test

Comment: @Simon Davies, OK, please try edited version. This should work on Mac. Make sure .htaccess is in TestPages folder.

Comment: thansk fro the feed back, but still no luck 403 forbidden permission etc, its if I remove the RewriteEngine On, then the page is ok, as a normal page not what I want etc so http://localhost/TestPages/index.php?page=newpage works but still http://localhost/TestPages/index.php/newpage does not.  thanks so far

Answer (score 0):

the answer came from here:
[Answer to my question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/381727/mod-rewrite-issue-in-setting-up-on-snow-leopard)

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

seems to be the break and it needing to be on one line?